# Video.play() causes TypeError

Tags: javascript, video, hover

I have a div with a function that starts a video while hover. This works just fine:

```
$('.portfolio-hover').mouseenter(function () {
    $('video', this).load();
    $('video', this).get(0).play();
})
$('.portfolio-hover').mouseleave(function () {
    $('video', this).get(0).stop();
})
```

But It causes errors in the console: Uncaught TypeError: $(...).get(...).stop is not a function. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

try  `$('video', this).get(0).pause();`

Comment: With changing stop() to pause(), I still get an error; "Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: The play() request was interrupted by a call to pause()"

Anyone has a clue why this is happening?